# How can I parse with regex name/value pairs separated by a colon?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string (faceted search query):

```
var q = ":salesRevenue:brand:Tchelicon:brand:Eurocom
:brand:Turbosound:brand:Labgruppen:brand:Tannoy:brand:Klarkteknik
:brand:Midas:brand:Bugera
:brand:Tcelectronic
:eligibleProduct:0010000066:publicProduct:false:brand:Behringer:productFilter:All:";
```

I want to split it to three separate strings: q_brand, q_pubs and q_product and my client wants it all in Regex.

q_brand consists of values with values preceded by "brand:" only.

q_pubs are values preceded by "eligibleProduct:" and "publicProduct:".

q_product are values preceded by "productFilter:".

I want to be able to capture them even if they interchange positions (ex. like the position of :brand:Behringer:)

The end result is expected to be:

```
var q_brand = "brand:Tchelicon:brand:Eurocom
:brand:Turbosound:brand:Labgruppen:brand:Tannoy:brand:Klarkteknik
:brand:Midas:brand:Bugera
:brand:Tcelectronic:brand:Behringer";

var q_pubs = "eligibleProduct:0010000066:publicProduct:false";

var q_product = "productFilter:All";
```

I tried using `(brand:.+:)` on `brand:apple:brand:orange:product:hello:brand:grain:` for one instance and several others but am getting unexpected results.

Comment: it is not semi colon. It is colon. Semi colon is this `;`

Comment: @SagarV OK, sorry for that. Rest assured it's just an honest mistake.

Comment: I think there's a faction that thinks "easy" regex questions don't belong here, so instantly downvotes them (and their answers).   It can be difficult for experts to remember that it's only easy when you already know how.  Don't sweat it.

Comment: They even got this amazing feature called censorship where they delete even my most harmless comments.

Comment: Back-and-forth discussion about "why the downvote" etc does tend to get deleted; I understand why that'd be frustrating but it is for the best (it gets tiresome to read through when you're just looking for code answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close -- the main problem in your attempt was that you included the trailing colon in your match, which interfered with later matches.

The general pattern is `(foo:[^:]+)/g)` -- this will match a fieldname "foo", followed by a colon, followed by any number greater than zero of characters which aren't colons, repeatedly.   Then the results are joined (again with colons) to fit your desired output.

for `q_pub` you have two different fieldnames, so is generalized to "\w+Product" (match any number of letter characters followed by Product.)

```js
var q = ":salesRevenue:brand:Tchelicon:brand:Eurocom:brand:Turbosound:brand:Labgruppen:brand:Tannoy:brand:Klarkteknik:brand:Midas:brand:Bugera:brand:Tcelectronic:eligibleProduct:0010000066:publicProduct:false:brand:Behringer:productFilter:All:";

var q_brands = q.match(/(brand:[^:]+)/g).join(":");
var q_pub = q.match(/(\w+Product:[^:]+)/g).join(":");
var q_products = q.match(/(productFilter:[^:]+)/g).join(":");

console.log(q_brands);
console.log(q_pub);
console.log(q_products);
```